# System.Memory: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-msal

Getting this error while running one of the function app  System.Memory: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Recently we have migrated from Active Directory Authentication Library(ADAL) to Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL).As part of that updated Azure.Identity to 1.10.2.But after migration we are facing issues with all function apps.

The initial issue we have faced while running the function  app is 'Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.15.0. As per investigation we found the issue is with Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets version.So we have resolved this issue by updating Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets with 4.6.1 beta version(Tried with latest stable version 4.5.0 but doesn't resolve the issue ).

But then we are getting Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0.

Able to fix the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=6.0.0. issue by updating the same with 6.0.0 in one of the function app which leads to another issue of  'System.Memory: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1'

I don't understand why it uses this version even though we are referencing 4.0.4.1 and how I can fix this problem. Even a clean reinstall of Visual Studio did not help

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below sample code to retrieve the secrets from the key vault with the function app.

**Make sure you have the below packages in your Function to work properly csproj :**

```html
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.39" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Code :**

```c
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

public static class Function1
{
    [Function("HttpTriggerFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1");
        logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string secretValue = await GetSecretFromAzureKeyVault(logger);

        return new OkObjectResult($"The secret value is: {secretValue}");
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetSecretFromAzureKeyVault(ILogger logger)
    {
        var keyVaultUrl = "https://<key_vault_name>.vault.azure.net/";
        var secretName = "<secret_name>";

        try
        {
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);
            var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);

            return secret.Value.Value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError($"Error retrieving secret: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I gave access to the function app to read the secrets from the key vault as below,

[image]

**Output :**

It runs successfully,

[image]

I retrieved the secret from the key vault with the above function app output **URL** as below,

[image]

Then, I published my project on the function app.

[image]

I ran the function app in the Azure portal and successfully retrieved the secrets from the key vault.

[image]